# grunt-contrib-uglify throws error when using function parameter with default value

Tags: javascript, node.js, grunt-contrib-uglify

I use Grunt 1.0.1 with grunt-contrib-uglify 2.0.0 to uglify concatenated .js files of my project. This has worked fine until today, where I introduced a JavaScript function with a function paramater which has a default value.

Now the Grunt task results in this error message:

```
Running "uglify:app" (uglify) task
JS_Parse_Error {
  message: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token operator «=», expected punc «,»',
filename: 'app.js',
```

The app.js line in concern as echoed by this task is:

```
function addNumbers(a, b=1){
  console.log(a + b); 
}
```

where the exact column in the line is where `b=1` is to be found.

If I remove the default value, everything works fine again.

Why is grunt-contrib-uglify complaining here? How can I get this solved?

Answer (score 4):

Referring to the Error message, you are obviously not using ES6. The way you are setting your default value for `b` will only work in ES6.

Here is what you can do to set a default value for `b`

```
function addNumbers(a, b) {
  b = b || 1;
  console.log(a + b); 
}
```

If you also want to accept `b` to have a value of `0`, then you could check if `b` is `undefined` and `||` not a `number` to set `b`'s default value to `1`.

```
function addNumbers(a, b) {
  b = (b === undefined || typeof b !== 'number') ? 1 : b;
  console.log(a + b); 
}
```

Comment: So, how could I force grunt-contrib-uglify to use ES6 rather than an outdated specification? Is this a matter of node.js version I'm running in my development environment? If so, I'm running v.4.5.0.

Comment: I would not consider this an outdated specification, but the node.js version does matter when it comes to ES6 feature support, you may want to take a look at the following table [Node.js ES2015 Support](http://node.green/), especially *default function parameters*, which is what you want to use. What you can do though is to add a task to your grunt file which will transpile your ES6 to ES5. Here is a grunt plugin that can do this for you [grunt-babel](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel).